# Update a specific array element if it fulfils at least one of several conditions

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to understand (and fix) a code that is not mine, which uses PyMongo.

We want to look for the document with `_id==_id` that has, inside its list `comments`, a comment with `id==comment_id` or `id==PyObjectId(comment_id)`.
To that comment we want to add an answer.
In code:

```py
await db_collection.update_one(
        filter=query, update=update, array_filters=array_filters
)
```

where

```py
query = {
    "_id": _id,
    "$or": [    
        {"comments": {"$elemMatch": {"id": comment_id}}},
        {"comments": {"$elemMatch": {"id": PyObjectId(comment_id)}}},
    ],
}

update = {
    "$set": {
        "comments.$[cmt].answer": jsonable_encoder(reply)
    }
}

array_filters = [{"cmt.id": comment_id}]
```

My problem is that `array_filters` only check if `id==comment_id` and not also if `id == PyObjectId(comment_id)`, like the query does.
This way when I have a `PyObjectId` as id, no item is updated.

I guess I should modify `array_filters` with something like

```py
array_filters = [{"cmt.id": comment_id}, {"cmt.id": PyObjectId(comment_id)}]
```

or

```py
array_filters = [{"$or$": [{ "cmt.id": comment_id}, {"cmt.id": PyObjectId(comment_id)}]}
```

but sadly I can just test my code on production and I'm trying to understand how this actually works before breaking things.

Thank you all!

Comment: Why not copy the production collection to a development collection, or perhaps even another server?

Comment: I don't know, but can guess, what `PyObjectId` is (not part of `pymongo`), but perhaps something like, [`array_filters = [{"cmt.id": {"$in": [comment_id, PyObjectId(comment_id)]}}]`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LNym8adcyNa)?

Comment: Or maybe even without `arrayFilters`, like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xw8JleA_20M).

Comment: @rickhg12hs The solution you gave me in mongoplayground is perfect! Please write it down as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you also for the mongoplayground site, it is just what I needed. I can copy the data manually, but not the whole database for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what's going on here...

From the original question:

```python
query = {
    "_id": _id,
    "$or": [    
        {"comments": {"$elemMatch": {"id": comment_id}}},
        {"comments": {"$elemMatch": {"id": PyObjectId(comment_id)}}},
    ],
}

update = {
    "$set": {
        "comments.$[cmt].answer": jsonable_encoder(reply)
    }
}

array_filters = [{"cmt.id": comment_id}]
```

The query is using `"$elemMatch"`, but since there is only one condition on a single field, this could be simplified to:

```python
query = {
    "_id": _id,
    "comments.id": {
        "$in": [comment_id, PyObjectId(comment_id)]
    },
}
```

If we *assume* (seems reasonable here, but we should be careful) that `"id"` is unique in the `"comments"` array, then [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) isn't necessary either.  So `update` may be simplified to:

```python
update = {
    "$set": {
        "comments.$.answer": jsonable_encoder(reply)
    }
}
```

Here `$` uses the element "match" from `query` and replaces ***the first***, and ***only the first***, matching element in `"comments"` for the `update`.  If more than one element of the `"comments"` array should be updated, this won't work (see below use of `"arrayFilters"` if more than one element should be updated because `"id"` is *not* unique).

So, putting it all together with the assumptions we've made:

```python
query = {
    "_id": _id,
    "comments.id": {
        "$in": [comment_id, PyObjectId(comment_id)]
    },
}

update = {
    "$set": {
        "comments.$.answer": jsonable_encoder(reply)
    }
}

# possibly some other code here from the original app ...

await db_collection.update_one(
        filter=query, update=update
)
```

See how it works with made-up documents on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uxbndOq4vt-).  Only one element is updated, even though there are duplicate `"id"` values.

#### With [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

If `"id"` is not unique within the `"comments"` array and multiple objects within the array should be updated, then `"arrayFilters"` can be used to do this.

```python
query = {
    "_id": _id,
    "comments.id": {
        "$in": [comment_id, PyObjectId(comment_id)]
    },
}

update = {
    "$set": {
        "comments.$[cmt].answer": jsonable_encoder(reply)
    }
}

array_filters = [
    {
        "cmt.id": {
            "$in": [comment_id, PyObjectId(comment_id)]
        }
    }
]

# possibly some other code here from the original app ...

await db_collection.update_one(
        filter=query, update=update, array_filters=array_filters
)
```

Here, any `"comments"` array element that "matches" the `"arrayFilter"` will be updated.  See how it works on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qZJOEnzWilH).  All elements that "match" the `"arrayFilter"` are updated.